# Does Unit Test mean that the test has to be mocked?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, integration-testing

Does Unit Test mean that the test has to be **mocked** or definition of Unit Test can be without mocked?

For example below, this test is mocked, so it is unit test:

```
/**
* @test
*/
public function it_should_return_true_if_ssh_client_is_connected()
{
    $this->phpSecLibShh->shouldReceive('isConnected')->andReturn(true)->once();

    $this->assertTrue($this->shell->connected($this->phpSecLibShh));
}
```

Example below, is this Unit Test or Integration Test? I am not clear about this:

```
/**
 * @test
 */
public function it_should_get_half_price_discount()
{
    $cost = 50;

    $order = new Order();

    // It does not connect to database or any other service
    $discounted = $order->discount(Order::DISCOUNT_HALF_PRICE, $cost);

    $this->assertEquals(25, $discounted);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main idea of mocking is to decouple the dependency. Unit tests shouldn't have any kind of dependency. Say your business logic connecting to database layer which in turn connects to database. Now you are writing a unit test to test your business logic. If you are not decoupling database base layer from business logic then your unit test will go and hit database, which should never happen. So what you should do is to inject the database dependency to business logic layer and when writing unit test mock that dependency.

Long story short you don't need mock always for unit tests but if any dependency then that should be mocked. If your test has any dependency (say database dependency, file dependency etc.) then your test is not unit test but integration test

Comment: Not according to Martin Fowler's [definition of Unit Test](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/UnitTest.html)... For him (and Kent Beck, creator of JUnit and TDD), in unit tests the units being tested don't necessarily have to be isolated from their dependencies. Personally, I think that isolated unit testing is generally a bad idea and should be avoided.

Comment: @Rogério I appreciate your comment. Unit tests are something we run quite a number a number of times. If we change event one line of code we may run the unit test to make sure the changes didn't affect any of the functional logic written so far. Now think that in your business logic your business logic you are calling an external paid web service. If you are not mocking that service then you will end up paying money for each time you run the unit test. I do agree with tests should be isolated but it should isolate from dependency as well. Isolation means a unit of code.

Comment: Of course, when calling "awkward collaborators (such as a remote credit card verification system)" as mentioned in Fowler's article, it does make sense to mock. Such situations, however, should be the exception rather than the norm, and very rare in most real-world codebases. The problem with mocking libraries is that inexperienced developers tend to abuse them a lot (as well as misuse them, given their inherent complexity). I know this from the experience of developing a mocking library for 12 years now, while supporting users all this time and seeing the mistakes they so frequently make.

Comment: @Rogério I would like to know your thoughts about other dependencies as well like database dependency, file dependency etc. Do you think that should be mocked?

Comment: I don't mock them. My integration tests run in database transactions which are always rolled back at the end of each test, so they don't interfere on each other. And they use the same shared DEV database used by the rest of the team, which is also used to run the app locally - in-memory databases like HSqlDb don't work well in practice.

Comment: @Rogério thanks for the reply. Then how do you differentiate between unit tests and integration tests? Also, how do even call your tests as a unit test as it is not testing unit of code but units of code? Next major issue of that approach would be, say you have a production build and as the part of CI/CD pipeline you should run your unit tests. If you are not mocking the DB dependency then it would end up writing data to the production database, which would be really worse.

Comment: I don't. There is no need/value for unit tests when the integration test suite is fast and reliable enough, which has been the case in my projects. We could call them "(sociable) unit tests" (using Fowler's terminology) - personally I care only that tests can be executed quickly and easily at any time. We have several Jenkins builds: CI, DEV, and PRD. Tests are only executed in the CI environment, using the DEV database. But, in any case, data changes are never committed to the database - always rolled back.

Answer (score 1):

Vijay, from my experience, the team will be the best judge to decide if they needs a solitary/social/adaptive unit testing strategy, since there is no "One size fits all solution".

Having said that, I believe being adaptive is probably more practical. Almost all of the mid to large sized monolithic applications will have atleast one external dependency which may not be available in the development/test environments( eg: payment gateway/ Decision engine ) . Mock data will be our only option here.
However with in the same unit test case we could club another sociable scenario too( by calling another function with in the same class/namespace). It may even be possible for the second function to have its on separate mocked test case. Thus it could become an adaptive unit testing strategy where the team takes a collective stand in terms of what they call an unit and what the strategy to be used on a scenario by scenario basis. 
We also should bare in mind that when we start building a deployment pipeline our unit test cases could be executed as part of an automated process which by itself be provisioning the enviroments. Hence it may be benificial to keep our unit testcases isolated from any database/file dependencies.

In future when more and more applications move into Microservice architecture and containerisation we'll have more clarity around the unit testing strategy to be used. Development /Deployment will be done in stateless and independently deployable/manageable chunks.  Tools like Docker Daemon APIs can be used to spin up a container which hosts a specific related/dependent service/functionality and run it as part of our test case execution , this will prevent us from having to mock other services , since we could easily activate a light weight container with the relevant service and test it.